# Input attribute type="number" doesn't work in IE11. How can I get around this?

Tags: html, forms, input, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple form and one of the input fields is of type **number**.

```
<input type="number" step="0.5" required/>
```

This works in most browsers. However on Internet Explorer 11 the validation for `type="number"` is flawed. It only allows numeric values, however after a number has been entered the validation seems to stop working.

For example, in most browsers the validation for `type="number"` works like this:

- 50 is a valid value
- example!50 is an invalid value
- 50example! is an invalid value

Whereas in Internet Explorer it works like this:

- 50 is a valid value
- example!50 is an invalid value
- 50example! is a valid value

How would I ensure that only numeric values are allowed in the input field for Internet Explorer (whilst also allowing step="0.5" to continue working - i.e 10.5 would still be valid even though "." is non-numerical)

Comment: Hi, may I know whether your issue has been solved or not? Is my answer below helpful to deal with the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix the issue with this regex:

```
~r/^\d+(?:\.[05])?$/
```

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the issue in IE 11. To solve the issue, we can add regex. The example code is like below, it allows for exactly one decimal and works well in IE 11:

```html
<input type="number" step="0.5" required oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" />
```